# Wrong Global SCSS/CSS Being Used

Tags: next.js

I have a Next.js app with two "layout" components:

**/layouts/default-layout.tsx:**

```
import { Footer } from '../components/footer';
import { Header } from '../components/header';

import './default-layout.scss';

export const DefaultLayout: React.FC = ({ children }) => (
  <div className="d-flex flex-column vh-100">
    <Header className="flex-shrink-0 fixed-top" />
    <main className="flex-shrink-0">
      {children}
    </main>
    <Footer className="mt-auto" />
  </div>
);
```

**/layouts/profile-layout.tsx:**

```
import Helmet from 'react-helmet';

import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
import './profile-layout.scss';

export const ProfileLayout: React.FC = ({ children }) => (
  <div>
    <Helmet
      link={[
        { rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins|Open+Sans|Dancing+Script&display=swap' },
      ]}
    />
    {children}
  </div>
);
```

Both layout components import some global SCSS styles.

Pages use one layout or the other like this:

```
const IndexPage: NextPage = () => (
  <DefaultLayout>
    {/* more content here */}
  </DefaultLayout>
);
```

Most pages use the default layout, but my dynamic pages at /pages/profiles/[id].tsx use the profile layout. Navigating between pages works fine and each page uses the correct layout and correct SCSS files.

But if I type a page directly into the web browser's address bar, I get inconsistent results. Often the wrong SCSS file is used. Having the app open in another tab and navigating around seems to effect it too.

How can I have the correct SCSS styles loaded consistently?

Comment: would you be able to share a repo with a minimal reproducible example or a codesandbox?